# Extract content from encrypted rar file with given password

Tags: python, passwords, extract, rar, compression

patoolib can be used to extra the content from a *rar* file, like:

```
import patoolib
patoolib.extract_archive("test.rar", outdir=".")
```

in case my *test.rar* file has the password *123*, how can I give the password as an argument to the extract_archive call?

Did not find anything in the documentation.
Is there any alternative, any other lib?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this library [here](https://pypi.org/project/rarfile/2.5/), which supports password-protected archives.